# Check when a QUERY is done from another PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, class, mysqli

I have a simple question, I use a class where inside I have:

```
/////MY CLASS

public function resetpassword($upass,$tokenrecover,$usermail)
{
    try
    {
        global $statreset;
        $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET user_pass = '".$new_password."' WHERE verification_token = '".$tokenrecover."'" );
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);            
        $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);
        if ($stmt->execute()){  
        $statreset ="TRUE";
        ......
```

now, I'm new about this stuff, and maybe the question would be stupid, but when I run the function from another page:

```
            ////OTHER_PAGE.PHP

            $user->resetpassword($upass,$tokenrecover,$usermail);
            echo $statreset;
            if ($statreset =="TRUE"){
            echo "query done";
            }
```

I put the variable $statreset and when I run the script on localhost everything is working... but is this the correct method? I mean, I'm trying in localhost, what if the server is slow?

the **if ($statreset =="TRUE"){** will run when the query from the class is done?

that does make any sense? there is another way to know when the query is done in a better way?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than declare a global, why not have the function return a value? E.g., in your resetpassword() function:

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    return "TRUE";
} else {
    return "FALSE";
}
```

Then in your other page:

```
$statreset = $user->resetpassword($upass,$tokenrecover,$usermail);
echo $statreset;
if ($statreset =="TRUE"){
    echo "query done";
}
```

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Comment: Thank you, I'm new about this stuff, but when I call : $user->resetpassword($upass,$tokenrecover,$usermail); the main page where I call that fuction will wait for the execution? so that the " echo $statreset;" will be echo fine? it make sense my question? thank you

Comment: No problem! Yes, it will wait for the execution. Your call to `resetpassword()` will run synchronously, and all function calls within the `resetpassword()` function (including database access calls) are also going to run synchronously. Therefore, you don't need any special code to wait for the return value--by default your code will already wait for the return value of `resetpassword()` before resuming execution.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way.

**resetpassword()** does not return the value.in another page does not get the result of the implementation of **resetpassword()**,if **resetpassword()** error, and throw an exception.

The resetpassword function captures the exception when it executes

**example**:

```
/////MY CLASS

public function resetpassword($upass,$tokenrecover,$usermail)
{
    try
    {
        $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET user_pass = '".$new_password."' WHERE verification_token = '".$tokenrecover."'" );
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);
        if (!$stmt->execute()){
            throw Exception("some error");
        }
        ......
    }



////OTHER_PAGE.PHP
try{
    $user->resetpassword($upass,$tokenrecover,$usermail);
    echo "query done";
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Message:' .$e->getMessage();
}
```